# How to toggle array values by their property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I would like to know how I can *toggle* values in my array by its property name.

For example having the following array I would like to toggle (button) all values that have property named **a** and/or **b** etc on and off.

**Input**

```
const arr_input = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3  },
  { a: 3, b: 9, c: 12  }
];
```

**Output**

```
const arr_output = [
  { b: 2, c: 3  },
  { b: 9, c: 12  }
];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdp0a539/

Comment: What do you mean by _"toggle"_? You seem to be asking, how to remove, and re-add values to an array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox correct. I would like to remove and then add the same value/multiple values. For example I would like to toggle 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use, `array.reduce` to filter out the property which you do not want in your output.

I have tried to replicate the situation, below, by using a `toggleArray`, in which you can pass a property, you don't want. It will filter out the array and give back the required output.

```js
var arr_input = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    b: 9,
    c: 12
  }
];

var toggleArray = function(propToToggle) {
  return arr_input.reduce((arr, inp) => {
    var obj = {};
    for(var key in inp) {
     if(key != propToToggle) {
       obj[key] = inp[key];
     }
    }
    arr.push(obj);
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

var arr_output = toggleArray('a');

console.log(arr_output);

arr_output = toggleArray('b');
console.log(arr_output);

arr_output = toggleArray('c');
console.log(arr_output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from your fiddle, the following will return a *copy* of the original array with the selected property removed

```js
const items = [
   { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3  },
   { 'a': 3, 'b': 9, 'c': 12  }
];

const toggleProperty = (value) => {
  return items.map(function(el) { 
    var o = Object.assign({},el);
    delete o[value];
    return o;
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="a" 
        onClick="console.log(toggleProperty('a'))">Toggle a</button>

<button type="button" id="b" 
        onClick="console.log(toggleProperty('b'))">Toggle b</button>

<button type="button" id="c" 
        onClick="console.log(toggleProperty('c'))">Toggle c</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a copy of the properties and filter the keys with an array.

```js
const toggle = (array, keys) =>
    array.map(o =>
        Object.assign(
            {},
            ...Object
            .keys(o)
            .filter(k => !keys.includes(k))
            .map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))
        )
    ),
    input = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3  }, { a: 3, b: 9, c: 12  }];

console.log(toggle(input, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(toggle(input, ['a', 'b']));
console.log(toggle(input, ['a']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to toggle (meaning that a property would be added again when you toggle the second time independent of the toggled state of any of the other properties), you need to maintain state, knowing whether currently a property is either on or off.

I would introduce an extra object for that, which would have all the properties, but for which the values are booleans: true when that property should be included, false otherwise.

Here is a working snippet that will display the object with only the properties that currently are "on":

```js
const items = [
       { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3  },
       { 'a': 3, 'b': 9, 'c': 12  }
    ],
    // Keep an object with same keys, but with all values set to true:
    state = Object.assign(...Object.keys(items[0]).map( key => ({ [key]: true }) ));

const toggleProperty = (key) => {
    // Toggle state, so you know which keys are currently off or on:
    state[key] = !state[key]; 
    // Produce the desired object and return it
    return items.map( obj =>
        Object.assign(...Object.keys(state).map( key => 
            state[key] ? { [key]: obj[key] } : {}
        ))
    );
}

// Handle the button clicks:
a.onclick = b.onclick = c.onclick = function () {
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(toggleProperty(this.id), null, 2);
    return false;
};
// At page load, show the complete objects (everything is toggled on):
output.textContent = JSON.stringify(items, null, 2);
```

```html
<button id="a">Toggle a</button>
<button id="b">Toggle b</button>
<button id="c">Toggle c</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```